# Обработка исключения

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

В блоке `try{}` происходит исключение `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException`

Как я понимаю, блоком `catch (Exception ex) {}` я обрабатываю любое исключение вызванное в `try{}`

Но при этом, вышеупомянутое исключение возникает и не обрабатывается.

Почему так происходит ? Как правильно обработать ?

```
    // Проверка на наличие элемента в DOM
    private bool ProverkaGotovnostiXPath(string xpath, IWebDriver Browser, TimeSpan vremyaOgidaniya)
    {

        // Таймаут
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser, vremyaOgidaniya);

        try
        {
            IWebElement elem = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog("", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас исключение происходит не в блоке `try`, а в делегате `e => e.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath))`,  если вы хотите его перехватить, то и обрабатываеть его надо внутри делегата.

Comment: @aepot понял, спасибо! до такого в своей программе обучения значит ещё не дошёл.

Comment: Не проще ли подписаться на `DOMContentLoaded`, после срабатывания события через JS повесить MutationObserver на родительскую ноду, куда добавляется нужный вам элемент и подписаться на собятия обсервера. Как только поймали нужную мутацию, останавливаете тем же яваскриптом обсервер, и получаете четко, с точностю до миллисекунд факт появления нужной ноды в дереве. И не нужен будет поллинг с ожиданиями того, что произойдет неизвестно когда. Покопайте JavaScript MutationObserver - шикарная штука.

Comment: @aepot А можно ли c помощью Selenium поставить точку останова ? Чтобы выполнение JS остановилось в нужном месте, изменить DOM и продолжить выполнение JS

Comment: Не уверен, что такое возможно.